# how can I integrate my existing web application running on application server(i.e.JBOSS) with node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have an existing web application running on Application server, which is basically a form designing module build on JSF 2.0.
Now I want to achieve a real time collaboration, like on one client one user perform an operation, should be visible to connected clients.
I want to broadcast the event performed on a client to connected clients.
I want to use Node.js to push the messages to the clients but as  per my requirement how can I integrate existing web application with node.js, as I have to listen the event source from node.js and an existing connection also required with node.js on a different port.
I am new to node.js, this is the first application i will build on node.js if possible.
Kindly suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can use node to run a [socket.io](http://socket.io/) server which will let the client communicate bi-directionally with the server. So long as every client connects to the same socket.io server it will seamlessly integrate with your existing application.

Comment: Of course, you can also use vanilla websockets, but socket.io offers greater browser support and a nicer API

Comment: I am looking forward to use socke.io, but can u suggest me how can i connect the socket server with my webpage on another application server? If i am running my application on jboss and browse the welcome page, then how can i get an active socket connection with the node.js server.. if I use var socket = io.connect('http://localhost'); to the socket server will it work.